# Coping with several Windows SDK versions on build server

Tags: c++, teamcity, winapi, build-server

We have a TeamCity build server with a couple of agents set up to build code on check in for several c++ projects. Now, we've run into some problems regarding handling dependencies on Windows SDK since

- It's to large to check-in and still be able to work with the source
  smoothly.
- Several can't be installed at the same time without problems.

The easiest way to set up TeamCity agents is to just install the Windows SDK. However, installing two versions the Windows SDK is problematic since it seems to overwrite registry entries of previous installations. Another approach is to cherry-pick files from the installation and put it on an rsync-server or the like, but the Windows SDK installer seems to modify Visual Studio binaries, etc so that does not feel good either. I've also checked with microsoft and they strongly suggested against cherry-picking files from the SDK install.

How have you set up your c++ projects on TeamCity and what would you suggest in our situation?

Comment: what problems have you had with multiple SDKs installed?

Comment: for example it overwrites a global registry entry that will obviously not work when running parallell builds for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make sure the versions of the SDK are installed in the same location on each machine that you use (both developer and build machine) then you can add a step to the start of your build scripts which sets the current SDK for use. You can do this either:

1. Using the registry settings (if you have only one build going at any time)
2. Using environment variables, which you reference in your project files for lib, bin etc.

I've seen this work pretty well before, although we we weren't using TeamCity.

Comment: I wish it was that simple. I always use environment-variables for libraries like boost that just installs to a folder. The windows SDK modifies the registry, systemfiles and even installed visual studio binaries... :-S

Comment: After googleing around, changing the registry settings seems to be a feasible solution although that would obviously hinder parallell builds.